# Compiler warning -fpermissive

Tags: c++, qt, compiler-errors, compiler-warnings

In my code I predefined some classes because they have references to each other like this:

```
class Light;
class Room;

class Light : public AbstractModel {
    int mId;
    QString mName;
    QString mAddress;
    bool mIsOn;
    LightType mType;
    QString mColor;

    int mRoomId;
    Room * mRoom;
public:
    Light();
    Light(const QString& name, const QString& address, int roomId, bool isOn, LightType type, const QString& color);
    virtual ~Light();

    const QString& Name() { return mName; }
    const QString& Address() { return mAddress; }
    int RoomId() { return mRoomId; }
    bool IsOn() { return mIsOn; }
    LightType Type() { return mType; }
    const QString& Color() { return mColor; }
    Room * Room();
    QList<Rule *> Rules();

    void setName(const QString& name);
    void setAddress(const QString& address);
    void setIsOn(bool isOn);
    void setColor(const QString& color);
    void setType(LightType type);
    void setRoomId(int id);

    static bool CreateIfNotExists();
    static bool Drop();

    static QList<Light *> GetAllLights();
    static Light * GetLight(int id);
    static Light * GetLightByAddress(const QString& address);
    static QList<Light *> GetLightsByRoom(int roomId);

    bool Insert();
    bool Update();
    bool Remove();
};

class Room : public AbstractModel {
    int mId;
    QString mName;
    QList<Light *> mLights;
public:
    Room();
    Room(const QString& name);
    virtual ~Room();

    const QString& Name() { return mName; }
    const QList<Light *> Lights();

    void setName(const QString& name);

    static bool CreateIfNotExists();
    static bool Drop();

    static Room * GetRoom(int id);
    static QList<Room *> GetAllRooms();

    bool Insert();
    bool Update();
    bool Remove();
};
```

On windows it compiles just fine but on ubuntu it gives me an error that the declaration of Room in the class Light changes the meaning of Room. I fixed it with the -fpermissive flag and now it's just a warning.

Why is it a problem in ubuntu?

The warning now is

```
../HomeControlApi/dbmodels.h:60:17: warning: declaration of ‘DbModels::Room* DbModels::Light::Room()’ [-fpermissive]
 Room * Room();
             ^
../HomeControlApi/dbmodels.h:29:7: warning: changes meaning of ‘Room’ from ‘class DbModels::Room’ [-fpermissive]
 class Room;
```

Comment: You can not fix anything by specifying `-fpermissive`, you only ignore the critical problem. Also the piece of code you posted is pretty far from [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and even does not seem to contain the lines that cause the warnings.

Comment: Can you indicate which lines correspond to the compiler messages please?

Comment: You have a method in Light named Room which is the same as the constructor from Room, so when you call Room() which one should it use?

Comment: @stark Thank you, I changed it and the warning is no more. Strange that the compiler on windows allowed it. The question is solved.